# Pandas dataframe filter for 'and' and 'or' clauses

Tags: pandas, dataframe, search, filter

I have a pandas dataframe column and I need to perform 'AND' search or 'OR' search based on the need. The search criteria elements are available in an array and the length of the this search array may vary during the runtime. Please see the code below:

```
import pandas as pd 
 
data = [['Adam Smith', 10], ['Dam Joshua', 15], ['Josh Willism', 14], ['Tim Robins', 14]] 

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'Age']) 

df 

search = ['dam', 'Josh']

# want to use or condition - expected to see 3 rows
emp = df[df['Name'].str.contains('|'.join(search), case=False)]

# want to use and condition expect to see 1 row i.e. Dam Joshua
emp = df[df['Name'].str.contains('&'.join(search), case=False)]
```

The OR clause seem to work for me and I have tried using & for AND criteria, but no luck.

Pleae suggest how python does this efficiently. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can string with `contains`

```
emp = df[df['Name'].str.contains(r'^(?=.*dam)(?=.*Josh)')]
```